# Spring-Boot Generic type in constructor needed

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

I've encountered a problem in my code and I'm looking for a workaround. This is the class:

```
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventBus;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcedAggregateRoot;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingRepository;
import org.axonframework.eventstore.EventStore;
import org.axonframework.repository.LockManager;
import org.axonframework.repository.PessimisticLockManager;
import org.axonframework.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BaseCommandHandler<E extends EventSourcedAggregateRoot> {

  protected Repository<E> repository;
  protected LockManager lockManager;

  /**
   * @param eventBus eventBus.
   * @param eventStore eventStore.
   */
  public BaseCommandHandler(EventBus eventBus, EventStore eventStore) {
    this.lockManager = new PessimisticLockManager();
    EventSourcingRepository<E> newRepository =
        new EventSourcingRepository<>(E.class, eventStore, lockManager);
    newRepository.setEventBus(eventBus);
  }
}
```

The first problem I faced was that I cannot use **E.class**. Then I changed the constructor to the following:

```
  public BaseCommandHandler(EventBus eventBus, EventStore eventStore, Class<E> type) {
    this.lockManager = new PessimisticLockManager();
    EventSourcingRepository<E> newRepository =
        new EventSourcingRepository<>(type, eventStore, lockManager);
    newRepository.setEventBus(eventBus);
  }
}
```

But when I ran the app it failed to start because of `Parameter 2 of constructor in com.domain.handlers.BaseCommandHandler required a bean of type 'java.lang.Class' that could not be found.`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: By its very nature, a Spring `@Component` class cannot be generic, since Spring wouldn't know what the generic type parameters are. Re-think what you're doing. --- If you need help with that, create a new question explaining what you're trying to do, and why you need it to be Spring-managed *and* generic at the same time.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas! I didn't know that, I'm learning spring. I was trying to abstract two command handlers that have similar structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GenericTypeResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html) class:

```
Class<E> type = (Class<E>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), BaseCommandHandler.class);
EventSourcingRepository<E> newRepository = new EventSourcingRepository<>(type, eventStore, lockManager);
```